# Unknown RR type in named - SRV exchange record

Tags: domain-name-system, exchange, bind, srv-record

I am trying to add an SRV record on Fedora 20 x64 on bind 9.

The record should reroute the mail for excahnge to a different port. So I add this SRV record:

```
_sumbission._tcp          IN SRV         10 10 20587 mail.mydomain.org.
```

And after I restart named, I get `unknown RR type '_submission._tcp'` and I am even more puzzled since I have a record in `/etc/services` as

```
submission      587/tcp         msa             # mail message submission
submission      587/udp         msa             # mail message submission
```

What am I doing wrong guys?

Comment: I tried this as the zone file:

$ORIGIN host.mydomain.org.
$TTL 1D
@       IN SOA  @ host.mydomain.org (
                    1   ; serial
                    1D  ; refresh
                    1H  ; retry
                    1W  ; expire
                    3H )        ; minimum
    NS  @
    A   my_public_ip
    IN MX       10      mail
    _sumbission._tcp IN SRV 10 10 20587 mail.mydomain.org.

Comment: Any leading whitespace or something like that? Including the zone file, properly formatted, in the question could help.

Comment: No. There is no leading space. I typed it in so many different ways. It does not seem to be the zone file since I tried to put this in a zone file that I am using all the time and it wll works with the exception of this _submission._tcp thing

Comment: I do not know what is the owner in this case. Give me an example please.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the error message I can only assume that the line for the `SRV` record looks something like this:

```
 _submission._tcp          IN SRV         10 10 20587 mail.example.org.
```

instead of what you probably intended, which is this:

```
_submission._tcp          IN SRV         10 10 20587 mail.example.org.
```

Ie, the left-most column, the owner name, has been left blank which means that the name from the previous record shall be used again for this record. And then, as the owner name has already been settled for this record, `_submission._tcp` has to be a value that should be used for the next column and the next mandatory column is the type column.

Hence the error saying `unknown RR type '_submission._tcp'`.

Comment: It is not the typo. I made the type when I posted on this forum. There is no typo in the actual zone file...

Comment: @BogdanBartos Are you referring to the "sumbission" typo? That is not what my answer was about.

Comment: I do not know what is the owner in this case. Give me an example please. –  Bogdan Bartos 7 secs ago   edit

Comment: The owner name is the left-most column. It's where you *want* to have `_submission._tcp` but where I suspect you may have whitespace.

Comment: What a mess! I had a tab in front of _submission. I thought it does not matter if you have whitespaces or tabs in front of a record... Anyway, the zone loaded properly now. Thank you soooo much!

Comment: @BogdanBartos Hence why I was asking if there was any leading whitespace (which there apparently was!) and posted an answer explaining the importance of having the owner name to the very left. If you found any answer particularly helpful please consider using the voting and/or accept answer functionality.